# Solr near real time search: impact of reindexing frequently the same documents

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine

We want to use SolR in a Near Real Time scenario.  Say for example we want to filter / rank our results by number of views.

SolR SoftCommit was made for this use case but:

- In practice, the same few documents are updated very frequently (just for the nb_view field) while most of the documents are untouched.
- As far as I know each update, even partial are implemented as a full delete and full addition of the document in lucene.

It seems to me having many times the same docs in the Tlog is inefficient and might also be problematic during the merge process (is the doc marked n times as deleted and added?)

Any advice / good practice?

Comment: Do you really need to update the documents that often? How about doing batch updates every five minutes (adjust as necessary) or something like that?

Comment: Thanks for you reply @MatsLindh. Yes, we try to keep the softcommit as long as possible to avoid cache invalidation while keeping data fresh enough. But from an architectural perspective, I am not 100% convinced that dealing with volatile data in SolR is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you could use for supporting this scenario:

1. [In place updates](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html): only that field is udpated, not the whole doc. Check out the conditions you need to be able to use them.
2. [ExternalFileFieldType](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/working-with-external-files-and-processes.html#WorkingwithExternalFilesandProcesses-TheExternalFileFieldType) you keep the values in an external file

if the scenario is critical, I would test both in reald world conditions if possible, and asses.

Comment: Hi @Persimmonium
1. I was not aware of those In place updates. Seems to be a good way of supporting the volatile data. I will dig a bit how it works under the hood! Thanks!
2. EFF seems to be a bit hard to manage properly with SolR cloud.